# VBscript conditional when trying to open a new SAP session?

Tags: vbscript, sap-gui

I have the following vbs code, that opens a new SAP session:

```
Option Explicit
Dim WSHShell, SAPGUIPath, SID, InstanceNo, WinTitle, Name
Set WSHShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
If IsObject(WSHShell) Then
    SAPGUIPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\"
    Name = """1. SAP ECC Production (PRD)"""
    SID = "PRD"
    InstanceNo = "00"
    WSHShell.Exec SAPGUIPath & "sapgui.exe " & Name & " " & _
      InstanceNo
    WinTitle = "SAP"
    While Not WSHShell.AppActivate(WinTitle)
      WScript.Sleep 250
    Wend
    Set WSHShell = Nothing
End If
```

There are two scenarios when executing it:

1. First, there's no other SAP session running, so works well, no issue here.
2. Second, there´s another SAP session already running, so the following windows is popped up.

[image]

What I want is to add a conditional to the code, that if the first case happens, does nothing, and if the second case occurs, selects the marked option,

Can anybody help me out please?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/50049675/692942

Answer (score 0):

Reference to below code in checking multiple logon occurred, and press the key you want (in your case, should press wnd[1]/usr/radMULTI_LOGON_OPT 2).

```
'Logon
'session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]").iconify  'hide windows
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-MANDT").text = Client
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-BNAME").text = User
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/pwdRSYST-BCODE").text = Password
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/pwdRSYST-BCODE").setFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/pwdRSYST-BCODE").caretPosition = 10
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
'if multiple logon, continue this logon and end others
If session.children.count > 1 Then
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/radMULTI_LOGON_OPT1").select
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/radMULTI_LOGON_OPT1").setFocus
    session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
End If
```

Answer (score -1):

With SAP, you can record and modify macros of everything you do. See [this link](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/08/04/script-recording-playback-for-dummies/).

Then just copy-paste the lines you need and write down your conditions.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow, thanks for your answer, just to say thn better than a bare link you should excerpt relevant information from the source to put before the link as stated in [answer], and no need to add a signature. You can then [edit] your answer and fix/improve it. Thanks